# delete cache by prefix in apc / memcache / eaccelerator

Tags: php, memcached, apc, eaccelerator

Let's assume I have these variables saved in apc, memcached and eaccelerator:

- `article_1_0`
- `article_1_1`
- `article_3_2`
- `article_3_3`
- `article_2_4`

How can I delete all cached variables that starts with `article_3_` (they can reach up to 10000) ?

is there any way to list the cached variables ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The slow solution

For APC:

```
$iterator = new APCIterator('user', '#^article_3_#', APC_ITER_KEY);
foreach($iterator as $entry_name) {
    apc_delete($entry_name);
}
```

For eaccelerator:

```
foreach(eaccelerator_list_keys() as $name => $infos) {
    if (preg_match('#^article_3_#', $name)) {
        eaccelerator_rm($name);
    }
}
```

For memcached, look at [@rik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785153/delete-cache-by-name-in-apc-memcache-eaccelerator/4785217#4785217)

#### The proper solution

The general solution for expiring multiple keys at once is to namespace them. For expiring them, you just have to change the namespace:

Say you have a group of keys "article_3_1", "article_3_2", .... You can store them like this:

```
$ns = apc_fetch('article_3_namespace');
apc_store($ns."_article_3_1", $value);
apc_store($ns."_article_3_2", $value);
```

Fetch them like this:

```
$ns = apc_fetch('article_3_namespace');
apc_fetch($ns."_article_3_1");
```

And expire them all by just incrementing the namespace:

```
apc_inc('article_3_namespace');
```

Comment: +1 for APCIterator, though it does require APC 3.1.1 or above

Comment: hi , what is the first parameter in APCIterator "user" ? i couldn't find anything about it in the manual !

Comment: It means _user_ cache entries; user cache entries are the variables set by [`apc_store()`](http://php.net/apc_store), etc. The other possible value for this parameter is `file`; file cache entries are the cached scripts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149322/key-groups-with-apc-cache/10114726#10114726 says that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Although the docs say APCIterator is available in apc >= 3.1.1, I'm on several systems that claim to have apc 3.1.9, however there is no APCIterator present.  If you don't have APCIterator at your disposal, give something like this a whirl:

```
$aCacheInfo = apc_cache_info('user');

foreach($aCacheInfo['cache_list'] as $_aCacheInfo)
    if(strpos($_aCacheInfo['info'], 'key_prefix:') === 0)
        apc_delete($_aCacheInfo['info']);
```

In this example we're checking for a prefix in the key, but you could use preg_match et. al and achieve something closer to what APCIterator provides.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a way to retrieve all keys from memcache](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/memcache.getextendedstats.php#98161) but it's very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

If there is possibility to use alternatives for memcached, [scache](http://scache.nanona.fi) supports structured keyspaces. With it you could store data to nested paths :

```
scache_shset($conn, 'article/1/0', $data10);
scache_shset($conn, 'article/3/0', $data30);
scache_shset($conn, 'article/3/1', $data31);
```

and eventually destroy data by deleting the parent node

```
scache_shunset($conn, 'article/3');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an APCIterator which helps you search through the keys in APC.
Instantiate the APCIterator.

APCIterator::valid() means that there are keys still to iterate trough. APCIterator::key() returns you the apc key. APCIterator::next() moves the iterator position to the next item.

```
// APC
$iterator = new APCIterator('user', '/^article_3_/');

while($iterator->valid()) {
     apc_delete($iterator->key());
     // You can view the info for this APC cache value and so on by using 
     // $iterator->current() which is array
     $iterator->next();
}
```

For memcache you can use [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php) and use [getAllKeys](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.getallkeys.php) method

```
// Memcached 
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('mem1.domain.com', 11211);

$items = $m->getAllKeys();

foreach($items as $item) {
    if(preg_match('#^article_3_#', $item)) {
        $m->delete($item);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is always better to give some explanation in addition to the code.

Comment: And as an extra, answer the full question. You are missing the part where OP asks for _is there any way to list the cached variables ?_

Comment: I have extended my answer. Thanks for your feedback :)