# filter a key/value (specially APC) data store items

Tags: php, regex, apc, key-value-store

When i start working with APC, I expected that there is a way to make categories for cached items not only key/value pairs. because i want to clear cache only for one application or only one part my application.
when i found that it is only key/value pairs, a new question bubbled in my head:
is there any way to filter keys in APC cache by REGEX not by exact key match?

Comment: i found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149322/key-groups-with-apc-cache/10114726#10114726

Answer (score 0):

APC has actually *filters* (in configuration) to filter out the files that should *not* be cached. Unfortunately, this is not what you want, there is currently no APC function to retrieve a list of keys based on a regex.

However you could,

- either [store](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) an array having a list of keys in APC
- maintain such an array in an *include* file (depending on how dynamic the list is)

In APC, say you have a list of keys

```
'x-orange' : value, 'x-apple' : value, 'x-banana' : value, 
'x-Life of Pi' : value, 'x-The Hobbit' : value,...
```

For instance, a categories array in an *include* file, or in an APC variable

```
$cats = array('Fruits' => array('orange','apple','banana'),
              'Movies' => array('Life of Pi', 'The Hobbit'), ...
```

Then you can retrieve the APC data by category

```
$mycat = ...; // eg Movies
foreach ($cats[$mycat] as $key) {
   echo "$key : " . apc_fetch('x-' . $key);
}
```

Comment: i found this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149322/key-groups-with-apc-cache/10114726#10114726) and i am wondering why there is no out of the box tool for handling this (may be i should make one)